# How turn off showing path on project pane in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

How I can turn off showing path to project on project pane in PyCharm?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible. Here's a request in the tracker that looks similar: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126014